# InvalidProgramException when trying to create a new type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, reflection.emit

I have the following code:

```
AssemblyBuilder newAssembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("CustomAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder newModule = newAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("CustomModule");
TypeBuilder newType = newModule.DefineType("CustomType", TypeAttributes.Public);
MethodBuilder newMethod = newType.DefineMethod("GetMessage", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
byte[] methodBody = ((Func<string>)(() => "Hello, world!")).GetMethodInfo().GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
newMethod.CreateMethodBody(methodBody, methodBody.Length);
Type customType = newType.CreateType();
dynamic myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(customType);
string message = myObject.GetMessage();
```

However, an exception is thrown on the last line when tryingto call `myObject.GetMessage()`:

> InvalidProgramException - Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

What is wrong with my code and why is this exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the lambda expression includes a string, which when compiled ends not with the method body but in the type's metadata. The `ldstr` instruction in the lambda refers to the string via a metadata token. When you get the IL bytes and copy then to the new method the `ldstr` in the new method will have an invalid metadata token.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say it's because of this line:

```
byte[] methodBody = ((Func<string>)(() => "Hello, world!")).GetMethodInfo().GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
```

I'm not sure exactly what signature `(Func<string>)( () => "Hello, world!" )` will have, but it probably won't be the correct one (one accepting an implicit parameter of your defined type).

I'd recommend using the method builder's `GetILGenerator` method to do this:

```
AssemblyBuilder newAssembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("CustomAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder newModule = newAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("CustomModule");
TypeBuilder newType = newModule.DefineType("CustomType", TypeAttributes.Public);
MethodBuilder newMethod = newType.DefineMethod("GetMessage", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);

var il = newMethod.GetILGenerator();
// return "Hello, world!";
il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, world!" );
il.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );

Type customType = newType.CreateType();
dynamic myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(customType);
string message = myObject.GetMessage();
```